# Advice on starting a job in USA

Tags: software-industry, employer-relations

I've been looking for a job in the USA as of new years, but since I'm currently employed I didn't put much effort into it as of last month.

I've been contacted by few companies as of last month but since I'm EU citizen I need a company which will provide sponsorship for me I decided to follow up on one company which seemed to fulfill all my job and sponsorship requirements.

We had chat over the skype, then I came to on site interview. I was really good at both and answered all the questions correctly and was hoping to get job offer as soon as possible.

As soon as I came back to my country I received another call from that company where they informed me that I've done great and that they would like to make me an offer. In my current company I have 30 days notice period and I told them I won't be able to hand in my resignation until I'm informed about next steps (paperwork etc) and how long would they take.

I received email on 25th of February, same day as the phone call. Content of the email was the offer and benefits which they offer me and that I was expected to show up in the USA on site on 25th of March and that one person from that company will coordinate with me and the lawyer handling the case.

So I answered their offer (which we agreed on the phone) and thanked them and saying that if they needed something from me that they let me know. So few days passed and I received no emails from them. At the time I wanted to inform them that I wont be able to show up at March 25th at their facility since we haven't done anything regarding that in the meantime so I wrote very long email to my point of contact in that company requesting that they explain the process for me including timelines and things I need to do so I know where to hand in the resignation and that I still didn't hand in my resignation.

Last Friday I got response from the them saying that they will get more info from the lawyer today (meaning last Friday). Again no response from the last Friday so I wrote another email today asking do they have news or updates from the lawyer but still no response and it's 4pm their time and I'm doubtful that I'll get response today.

Finally I'm coming to my question(s):

What would you advice me to do? How would I get them to react faster or to get more insight of what is going on. Because I'm receiving offers from other companies and I'm not answering them hoping that this is pretty much done deal. I mean I liked what I saw there on site and I like the technologies and the people so waiting for me is not a problem I've got a job but how long should I wait?

Comment: does this company do this often (hire people who are not US citizens)? This should drastically affect how you should handle it.

Comment: @enderland yes I made them aware of my status and the said that they have no experience with sponsoring people from Europe but only from Pakistan and India

Comment: meaning they've probably worked with some of the large Indian and Pakistani body shops that bombard the INS with tens of thousands of H1b applications a year, swamping the system to the extent that people from other parts of the world find it impossible to get a work permit for the US at all. They probably never tried to get one issued themselves.

Comment: H1B is a lengthy process. Ask your employer to lay out the individual steps and to be informed about any one of them. Mine got stuck somewhere on an HR desk, so you want to personally keep this moving. In 2012 H1b quoat ran out on June 11, so I would not wait too long for this. I'd budget 6-12 weeks for the whole process.

Comment: Note I voted to reopen, as I think that this is a question probably lots of people from other parts of the world would want to know when moving to the US.

Comment: I agree with Amy its a specific q ie what steps do you need to do to work in X country

Answer (score 6):

**Danger Will Robinson!** Moving overseas is something not to be taken lightly. Be sure you have all your ducks in a line before even thinking about it! While it may be tempting to think that everything will work out, the risk if it doesn't is so much higher than taking a job locally that you need to exercise extreme caution.

In your specific case, it sounds like this company is not ready to have you come over, and even if they are really pushing to have a quick start, I'd hold off until you get the issues below sorted.

### General Caveats

Most companies in the world do not have much experience hiring workers from your country. This is so incredibly important I cannot express it enough. Visa requirements, paperwork, translations of paperwork from non-English countries, translations to other languages to non-English countries, bureaucracy, immigration restrictions, etc. etc. etc. make this a minefield for most candidates of any position.

Do not trust that the company knows what they are doing. Unless you are going to be writing code for the US state department, you need to learn to be responsible for watching your own back so that you don't end up in a horrible situation.

### 1) Know Visa Requirements

Many of my (US citizen) friends who lived in Japan and married a Japanese national went to move back home only to realize that it takes (at least) 6 months to get a visa, costs thousands of dollars for an immigration attorney, and is a maze of paperwork and visits to local government offices and consulates abroad. And this is for someone from a highly developed country who is married to a US citizen!

There are a dozen different types of visas, different requirements for each visa, different restrictions on work types and terms, and all sorts of other pitfalls in the process. You need to become an expert yourself.

1. **Figure out your visa type** Depending on your industry and job description, you will fall in to different visa categories. Make sure you understand what the visa is, what restrictions there are, if there are any limitations on quantity issued each year, what the chance of renewal is, and any other information that can be gathered on the web.
2. **Figure out what paperwork is required to apply** Your company, even if they have an immigration lawyer, likely won't have any clue what the actual documents you need to get in your country are, where you can get them, or what they're called. You need to understand what paperwork is required and start gathering it to be prepared, otherwise the process will take much longer.

### 2) Negotiate Your Contract Well Before Coming

Don't just take their word for anything. They may offer pay package X and tell you to come over, but it's just not that simple. Moving overseas is hugely expensive, and very difficult to cancel in a short period, so make sure all the ducks are lined up before hopping on that plane. Some things to consider:

1. **Termination On Loss of Visa** Many contracts for foreign workers will say that the employer has the right to terminate the contract if you lose your visa/permission to work. If your company is sponsoring you for the visa, this gives them an easy out to screw you over if they so desire, or otherwise give them leverage over you. While they will argue they have no control over whether you are issued a visa, at least put in language that says the employer is responsible for timely submission of paperwork for visa renewal, and that if they will not renew the contract/renew the visa sponsorship, they are required to give you 6 months prior notice.
2. **Payment on Termination of Contract** Many contracts have no provisions for how you will get home afterwards. Make sure that your contract contains a provision for either a severance package on termination of the contract for any reason (so you're not stuck with no money and no way home), or a company-paid move to a country of your choosing at the end of the stint (they may want to restrict you to moving back to your home country, but this is a global marketplace, and try to get it a bit broader than that)
3. **Expenses for Moving to Take the Job** Many companies will not pay you any money to actually move to the location where the job is. This can be very expensive. Ideally, the company will pay your expenses for relocating. Depending on the size of the company, this may not be realistic. At a bare minimum get a provision in the contract stating that if the company terminates the contract within X months (at least 12, preferably 18 or 24) then they will reimburse you X amount.
4. **Time Before Starting Work** When you move overseas, you will need time to find housing, open a bank account, get a driver's license, go to immigration or local city offices, etc. Make sure that the company either gives you time before you start to do that, or that they will not charge you vacation days for those things.

Whatever you end up negotiating, make sure the contract is signed before you buy a plane ticket. Don't sell away your rights counting on the company to do the right thing later on -- if they are going to do the right thing, there's no harm in them doing the right thing now.

### 3) Quality of Life

Most companies are not used to foreign workers from your company. And it's a challenge living abroad because of cultural differences. Make sure that the location of the job is acceptable to you (ideally you will visit before moving there). Make sure that you find a support group of some form. You will undergo culture shock, and your company may not understand or be supportive of what you're experiencing. Understanding what will happen, and being able to objectively explain to your employer what to expect will make all parties feel a lot happier. If there is a language barrier, it will be even tougher, and just be sure you're mentally prepared.

Some things you may want to discuss with your employer on this front:

1. **Unpaid leave for bereavement, etc.** If one of your parents passes away, it's not just a short drive to attend the funeral. Be sure your employer is understanding that traveling for these sorts of things isn't something you can plan for, and that you won't be penalized for having a family member pass away
2. **Paid Leave for Visa-related Duties** If you have to renew your passport, or go to the embassy to file paperwork, then you should be sure that your boss is happy with letting you do that on the clock. If not, at least realize that you will likely lose 2-3 days a year because of something administrative.
3. **Ability to Take Longer Vacations** Some companies are reluctant to let an employee leave for 2 weeks at a time. When you live far away and need to spend $2,000 on a plane ticket, travel for 12+ hours to get there, and move several time zones, you want to make good use of a single trip for a longer time. Make sure the company is okay with that, otherwise you may find yourself far more unhappy than you need to be.

It isn't enough to say, "This is a good job opportunity" as if it were in the same place you're living now. You are relocating for work, which is a huge commitment on your part. For the company it likely isn't half as much of a large commitment (they just have to hire an immigration lawyer). Be sure that it is a great opportunity, and worth the headaches before taking the plunge.

Comment: When my husband moved here on a fiance visa, we didn't have an attorney. It's not that big a deal--you just go to the INS or whatever they're calling it these days website and follow the directions. It does take a long time and isn't cheap, even without a lawyer, but you don't HAVE to have a lawyer. Possibly a lawyer would be able to speed up the timetable somehow.

Comment: Fiance visa is much different from a spousal visa, and the requirements are much more complex when dealing with a country like Japan (with a different language, complex documents, and tons of bureaucracy). I have friends who did it without a lawyer, but a single mistake in the paperwork was equivalent to essentially restarting the entire process (and delaying the move of the spouse). That couple had to live apart for months while waiting for the paperwork, and was generally a huge hassle.